# How to create an automatic push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications

Apologies if this has been asked already - I've tried searching around but couldn't find an answer.

Could someone guide me on how to implement an automatic push notification functionality. I'm building a chat app and want to send off a push notification to all relevant parties whenever someone sends a new message. The messages are stored in my Firebase server.

I assume I would need to use background fetch?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did u google it ? https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: way too broad and done on server side too... plus yeah.. google might help.